# Lightdm won't start after upgrade from 14.10 to 15.04

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, lightdm

After upgrading from 14.10 to 15.04, lightdm won't start.

```
Failed to start lightdm.service: Unit lightdm.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

I have a HP Spectre x360 with Intel Core i7-5500U with Intel HD Graphics 5500. I have tried most of the things I could find on forums with no success.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I had no drivers for video. I didn't have `xserver-xorg-core` installed. (I also reinstalled unity).

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-intel
```

And then I had an issue with login screen ([Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop))

```
chown username:username .Xauthority
```